# SendGrid Activity Tab: No Data

Tags: sendgrid

I am using SendGrid in my Azure Portal to send email from my VM.  I have had some issues with emails being sent / delivered.  I login to my SendGrid Account, go to Dashboard, click Activity and it shows "No data to display".  Do I need to do any setting to be able to see a log of emails sent?

Answer (score 1):

I had created a case with SendGrid and got solution from Shawn (lots of thanks).  I was logging to the website with my email address, and not with my SendGrid User ID in Azure Portal.  After I logged in with correct User ID, Activity showed up! SOLVED!